# How do I see my system volume level when changing it?

Tags: unity, volume-control

Back when I used 10.04 LTS and would change my system volume via custom keyboard shortcuts I would always get a nice volume level box that would appear to the top right corner of the screen. I had this also happen when I changed my display brightness.

Now I am on 12.04 and using Unity desktop. When I change my display brightness the brightness level box appears as expected like so

[image]

but when I change my volume level via custom keyboard shortcuts I get no volume level box showing up indicating a volume change has taken place. All I see is that little panel notification speaker icon's sound waves change a little bit. 3 levels is not enough feed back though.

**So how do I get a nice volume level box to show up when changing the volume?**

**UPDATE 1**
Tried to fix the keyboard shortcuts using aleprovencio's suggestions but it broke what already did work.

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

Weird I am able to get the volume level box to show up when I use the volume wheel on my computer

[image]

but I want to make it show up with the custom keyboard shortcuts I created in Ubuntu Tweak like in the image below:

[image]

Now the question is:

**What are the system commands that trigger both the volume changes and the volume level boxes to appear?**

Comment: That's strange, on my two notebook installs the volume notifications worked out of the box.

Comment: The volume level notification should still be there by default - see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD#Volume_changes .  I'm afraid I can't tell you where to configure this, though.

Comment: That seems like a bug. Does the volume even change, or is it just the notification that is missing?

Comment: @Cumulus007 Yes the volume changes when I use the commands: `amixer ser Master toggle-q`, `amixer set Master 5%+-q` and `amixer set Master 5%--q` like I show in UPDATE 2. I have those commands attached to keyboard shortcuts but they do not trigger the volume level box to appear. There must be another command to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: So your keyboard does not offer dedicated keys to change your volume?

Comment: @Cumulus007 no, my laptop just has this buggy volume wheel

Answer (score 3):

Ahh. Finally I figured out how to make this work. I was trying to find a way to customize 12.04 keyboard shortcuts and came across a post on another forum. To fix this all I had to do was go

**System Settings** > **Hardware** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** (tab) > **Sound and Media**

and the top three options are

- Volume mute
- Volume down
- Volume up

To the right of those options are where the key combinations are located. Click on one of them and it says **New Accelerator** at which point you press your new shortcut key combo and presto.

[image]

Comment: That's correct. The way you were doing it before wasn't going to work because you were calling a command which bypassed the daemon which shows volume notifications. (And PulseAudio, for that matter, which can cause problems: it does some very handy stuff for us that isn't easily expressed when talking to amixer directly). When you set the volume control keyboard shortcut in System Settings, that is the shortcut being watched for by gnome-settings-daemon. It takes care of all the weird stuff on its own.

Answer (score 0):

The actions you're looking for are: XF86AudioRaiseVolume, XF86AudioLowerVolume and XF86AudioMute. Just assign the keyboard shortcuts to them and you're fine.

Comment: That did not work at all. Posted a screen shot. It actually broke my old working custom keyboard shortcuts for volume

Comment: also look at UPDATE 2

Comment: aren't those the names of the custom keys? instead of the commands...

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to install `xfce4-volumed`.